# Getting a TinyMCE dropdown image list in an MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

I am trying to get an MVC3 app to feed TinyMCE with an external image list javascript file.  I have TinyMCE set up so that if I use a static image list file, I get the image list, so I know that part works.  But since I need to dynamically create the image list per user, I need something more flexible than a static file.  It is down to providing the javascript from the following controller action:

```
    public JavaScriptResult TinyMCEImageList(int id)
    {
        ListHelper lh = new ListHelper();
        string js = "var tinyMCEImageList = new Array(\r\n" + "// Name, URL\r\n";

        Dictionary<string, string> dict = lh.GetPetImageURLs(id);

        int i = dict.Count();
        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            js += "['" + item.Key + "', '" + item.Value + "']";
            if (i > 1)
            {
                js += ",\r\n";
            }
            i--;
        }
        js += "\r\n);";

        return JavaScript(js);
    }
```

The ListHelper.GetPetImageURLs() returns a dictionary object, which is simply a convenient way to hold the caption and URL of each image.  When I call this controller from the browser, with the appropriate id parameter, I get what I would think is a workable JS file.  In fact, such results are what I used to create the static file I used to test the TinyMCE image list setup, and that got me an actual dropdown image list.

Here is my TinyMCE setup.  This is inside the view containing a TinyMCE instance:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    plugins: "lists,pagebreak,style,table,inlinepopups,advhr,advimage,preview,searchreplace,print,paste,visualchars,nonbreaking",

    theme_advanced_buttons1: "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,forecolor,backcolor,image",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,advhr,|,preview,print,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak",

    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,

    external_image_list_url: "/InstructionDocument/TinyMCEImageList/@ViewBag.PetID"
});
```

The @ViewBag.PetID is being used elsewhere, so I know it is valid.  Even if I hardcode this value, or specifically point to the controller action, I still do not get a dropdown list of images.  I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing; can someone point out to me what it is (or at least give me some reasonable guidance)?

[EDIT]

The output from the TinyMCEImageList() action follows:

```
    var tinyMCEImageList = new Array(
            // Name, URL
            ['System Guinea Pig - 4', 'http://www.remindapet.com/Content/images/galler/1_4_970BB64F7C1A4375AF5722B8A62C8708.jpg'],
            ['System Guinea Pig - 5', 'http://www.remindapet.com/Content/images/gallery/1_4_CBA0D3DDBBED41C583A6E6C46FC9DADF.jpg']
    );
```

Also, here are the headers for the above javascript return from the action:

```
    Server  ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
    Date    Fri, 23 Dec 2011 00:14:31 GMT
    X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
    X-AspNetMvc-Version 3.0
    Cache-Control   private
    Content-Type    application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length  292
    Connection  Close
```

So, the action really is returning a JavascriptResult.  I just haven't been able to come up with how to get TinyMCE to see it.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the final output of your `TinyMCEImageList()` method?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, eth0.  I've edited the question to contain the output of the action, including the HTTP headers that are returned.  I can't help but think there's some special trick in how to call the action from the TinyMCE config code.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rendering an javascriptresult, create a js file while you are rendering the page.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    MakeJSFile();
    return View();
}
```

*MakeJSFile()* function will create the jsfile we need, then the page will be rendered.

**MakeJSFile() function**

```
public void MakeJSFile()
{
    #region declare
    var imgPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/gallery/");
    var jsPath = Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/image_list.js");
    List<string> fileList = populateList(imgPath, ".jpg");
    #endregion

    #region build jsfile
    string content = "var tinyMCEImageList = new Array(";
        foreach (var item in fileList)
        {
            content += "[\"" + item + "\", \"/Content/img/" + item + "\"]";
            if (item != fileList.Last())
                content += ",";
        }
    content += ");";
    #endregion

    #region create file
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(jsPath, false);
    sw.Write(content);
    sw.Close();
    #endregion
}
```

First declare the path for the directory where the images is, and also the path of the jsfile. Then create a list that contains the filenames and populate it(with populateList function).
Then create a string to build the jsfile.
After that create the file in you server.

You only need to do one more thing, create the *populateList* function.

**PopulateList function**

```
public List<string> populateList(string path, params string[] extensions)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
    DirectoryInfo di = fi.Directory;
    FileSystemInfo[] fsi = di.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileSystemInfo info in fsi)
        foreach (var ext in extensions)
            if (info.Extension == ext)
                list.Add(info.Name);
    return list;
}
```

This function requires the path to the directory and file extensions.

If you want a specific list, just change this function.

One more thing, don't forget to change the value of **external_image_list_url**

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...

    external_image_list_url: "/Scripts/image_list.js"
});
```